# Is there a unique per-app and secured identifier in Android

Tags: android, security, encryption

I would like to use an identifier that is unique per app, and cannot be obtained outside of the application context.
(Similarly to iOS's [identifierForVendor](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIDevice_Class/Reference/UIDevice.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIDevice/identifierForVendor))

I would like to get such a value to use inside a webview (Phonegap application) to do client-side encryption and use this value as password. (so values that are shared between applications are not valid, nor do values that are public, such as application id or package)

Is there such an API?

Thanks,
Nadav

Answer (score 0):

> I would like to use an identifier that is unique per app, and cannot be obtained outside of the application context

There is no such identifier. You are welcome to generate a UUID of your own, and store it on internal storage, though rooted device users can still get at it.

> I would like to get such a value to use inside a webview (Phonegap application) to do client-side encryption and use this value as password.

That would be fairly pointless, as anyone who wants to will be able to get the encryption key and decrypt the data. Have the user type in a passphrase, and use that as the key (or the basis of the key, where you use bcrypt/scrypt/PBKDF2 rounds to generate the actual key).

Comment: To further clarify, don't store the key in any persistent storage.